# Can I apply for a US and Canada tourist Visa at the same time?

Tags: visas, usa, canada

I applied for the Us tourist visa and will have the interview in a 2 weeks. Can I apply for a Canada tourist visa as well (I want to visit both places obviously), before getting the US visa?

Basically can I run both processes concurrently?

Comment: Yes. Why do you think you shouldn't?

Comment: Perhaps because the OP's passport must be sent with the application...and (presumably) the OP is applying with a single passport.

Answer (score 1):

If you [*apply online*](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/visit-canada/apply-visitor-visa.html) for a visa from Canada, you do not need to submit your passport straight away, so it's OK if the passport is elsewhere during that time.

If you need to [give biometrics](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/campaigns/biometrics/how-to-give-biometrics.html), Canada will mail you a letter and send an email, and you have 30 days from the date on that letter to give biometrics. You need the passport to identify yourself when you give biometrics.

Finally, at the end of the process, you need to submit the passport to the consulate when Canada asks for it, to receive the visa.

If you apply via a VAC or by mail, you do need to submit your passport with your documents.

Comment: Fair enough. But with two applications pending concurrently, both visa agencies could request the applicant's passport, and the times for production might conflict. That would be uncomfortable at best, and perhaps fatal for the application(s) at worst.

Comment: @David In this scenario, the passport is already at the US consulate.

Comment: If the passport will be returned to the OP at the interview, then it's probably safe to apply for the Canadian visa now. Difficulty would only arise if the Canadians (or their agent) wants the passport before the US consulate returns it.

Comment: They have at least 30 days to go to biometrics for Canada, so unless their US visa application goes to administrative processing it should be complete before then. And if that happens they can ask for the passport back.